# Optimizing CUDA kernels regarding registers

Tags: optimization, cuda

I'm using the CUDA Occupancy calculator to try to optimize my CUDA kernel. Currently I'm using 34 registers and zero shared memory...Thus the maximum occupancy is 63% for 310 Threads per block. When I could somehow change the registers (e.g. by passing kernel parameters via shared memory) to 20 or below I could get an occupancy of 100%. Is this a good way to do it or would you advise me to use another path of optimizing?

Further I'm also wondering if there's a newer version of the occupancy calculator for Compute Capability 2.1!?

Comment: Just a hint: I would not worry too much about occupancy unless you have noticed that that is what is holding your performance down. 63% can actually be quite a good figure. A better approach (IMHO) is to fully profile your application and figure out where performance problems lie.

Comment: Via Visual Profiler? Is this also possible easily when using CUDA in a MATLAB mex-file?
**Coalescing is only refering to global memory**, so I don't have to do anything with constant memory to optimize, right? (e.g. certain form of read-access or so)?

Comment: Constant memory is just global memory read through a cache, so there is the standard coalescing rules and limitations lurking in the background, just somewhere on the other side of the cache. But the problem is more insidious that just coalescing. Because of the interface between SM and constant cache, there is serialization in cases where threads within the same warp try and access different addresses in constant memory simultaneously. So you need to be careful with constant memory, but in a different way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some points to consider:

1. 320 threads per block will give the same occupancy as 310, because occupancy is defined as active warps/maximum warps per SM, and the warp size is always 32 threads. You should **never** use a block size which is not a round multiple of 32. That just wastes cores and cycles.
2. Kernel parameters are passed in constant memory on your compute 2.1 device, and they have no effect on occupancy or register usage.
3. The GPU design has a pipeline latency of about 21 cycles. So for a Fermi GPU, you need about 43% occupancy to cover all of the internal scheduling latency. Once that is done, you may find that there is relatively little benefit in trying to achieve higher occupancy.
4. Striving for 100% occupancy is usually never a constructive optimization goal. If you have not done so, I highly recommend looking over Vasily Volkov's presentation from GTC 2010 ["Better performance at lower occupancy"](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf), where he shows all sorts of surprising results, like code hitting 85% of peak memory bandwidth at 8% occupancy.
5. The newest occupancy calculator doesn't cover compute 2.1, but the *effective* occupancy rules for compute 2.0 apply to 2.1 devices too. The extra cores in the compute 2.1 multiprocessor come into play via instruction level parallelism and what is almost out of order execution. That really doesn't change the occupancy characteristics of the device at all compared to compute 2.0 devices.

Comment: Okay thanks so far. Could you please answer my question in the above comment (marked bold) :)?

Comment: Just this once. If you have a different question, you should ask another question, not keep tacking extra stuff onto an existing one.

Comment: Yeah sure, just felt somehow strange about opening a topic about such a 'small' question. But yeah, I will in the future, thanks though!

Answer (score 5):

talonmies is correct, occupancy is overrated.

Vasily Volkov had a great presentation at GTC2010 on this topic: "Better Performance at Lower Occupancy."

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf